# recursion relation for sequence of random variables

Tags: stochastic-processes, recurrence-relations

Let $\dots, \xi(-1),\xi(0),\xi(1),\dots$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables on $\mathbb Z$ with $\mathbb E[\xi(n)]=0, \mathbb E[\xi(n)^2]=1$.

The process $(X(n))_{n\in \mathbb Z}$ is recursively defined by

$$X(n+1) = \frac{1}{2}X(n) + \xi(n)$$

What is an explicit process $X(n)$ that fulfills this relation?

For whatever I do, I need an initial condition for the recursion relation, say $X(0)=\xi(0)$, but since this is not provided one can somehow solve this differently. How to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X \left( n \right)$ could be characterized as an infinite sum of i.i.d.
variables
$$ X \left( n \right) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^k \xi
   \left( n-k-1 \right) $$
(This is called the representation of a recursive (autoregressive) process as an infinite moving average process).

From that formula you could easily derive many of its properties (such as moments).

Comment: Thanks! If I'm not mistaken, your process is $X(n+1)$, otherwise it solves $X(n+1) = 1/2 X(n) + \xi(n+1)$. Now given this process I can verify it, but how would you approach such an infinite recursion without having initial conditions? Is there a constructive method or is it always "guess and verify"?

Comment: @madison54 There is an algebraic way to construct such solutions using the lag operator. You could look at a different example at another of my answers here http://math.stackexchange.com/a/338736/48763

Comment: @madison54 I recommend Brockwell and Davis "Time series: Theory and Methods" for a good introduction. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lag_operator

Comment: @madison54 I changed the index in my answer. However, for such models, it is more convenient to write $X(n+1) = \frac{1}{2}X(n) + \xi(n+1)$ instead.